# Averaging column data in R for a range of values

Tags: r

My dataset (testdata) is arranged like this:

```
           Time    1       2        3
1           0   569.607  557.689   527.353
2           1   569.208  556.697   527.162
3           2   569.278  556.919   528.125
4           3   570.059  555.621   527.158
```

I need to find and tabulate averages for columns 1, 2 and 3 during specific ranges of time. For example, I need averages of column 1 where time is 20-30, then for 40-50, then for 60-70.

In order to find the average for 20:30, I have used:

```
 sapply(testdata[testdata$Time %in% c(20:30), ],mean)
```

which results in

```
Time     1        2         3 
25.5000 570.5897 557.3413 528.5433
```

This is ok for one time range, but I'd like to calculate several at once - is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Would be easier to provide complete answer if you shared your sample data using dput function in r

Comment: See `?cut` and `?aggregate` -- something like `aggregate(. ~ cut(Time, c(0, 20, 30, 40)), testdata, mean)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If df is your dataframe, you can try the following:

```
ranges <- list(20:30, 40:50, 60:70)
t(sapply(ranges, function(x) sapply(df[df$Time %in% x,], mean)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map this to a function:

```
h <- function(x,y){
sapply(testdata[testdata$Time %in% c(x:y), ],mean)
```

then you can easily do `h(20,30)` or anything you want.

You can then use `purrr::map_chr()` to map that function to any range of values.